# Whats the rails way of handling many-to-many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

Ok so I have a photos model and controller that handles photos.. I have two other models restaurant and dish that I want to be able to have photos handled by the photo model.  So I created the photos model which as a polymorphic reference to either the dish or restaurant database tables.  Should I be using the restaurant controller to handle uploading restaurant photos and same for the dish controller or should I be using the photo controller to handle uploads for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to use polymorphic classes is that their business (or whatever) logic is very same, only difference is their data structure (which has got similar part as well). So you should use or polymorohic models with single controller, or separate classes (models) with separate controllers.

And of course you can use separate controllers for your polymorphic models, but it is out of best practices I think

Answer (score 0):

With this scheme you can think of photos as somewhat complex attributes for Restaurant and Dish records. So I would probably deal with uploading photos in the same place where other attributes for restaurants and dishes are handled. In a RESTful scheme this would happen in the new/edit actions in restaurants_controller and dishes_controller. The whole file uploading process can be helped considerably with a good plugin like [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

Comment: The only trouble with putting it in the new/edit actions is that I want users to have the ability to upload multiple photos and not just one per dish/restaurant.  Should I just create a new action called maybe new photo / edit photo?

Comment: You can use ajax to have a "smarter" form that allows you to add multiple pictures in one view. You can also check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3) railscast for some ideas about making complex forms.